# readHTMLTable in R, gets three varieble all named NULL, with the table inside one of them

Tags: r

The table itself looks correct, but i can't access the columns in the table. Is there any way to create a table with columns Fighter, Streak and Timeframe?

```
url <- "http://www.fightmatrix.com/ufc-records/title-defenses/"

data <- readHTMLTable(url, header = TRUE)

str(data)
```

Results in:

```
List of 3
 $ NULL: NULL
 $ NULL:'data.frame':   30 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ Fighter  : Factor w/ 30 levels "Anderson Silva",..: 10 1 14 17 18    25 19 16 28 22 ...
  ..$ Streak   : Factor w/ 11 levels "10","11","2",..: 2 1 11 10 9 8 7 6 6 5 ...
  ..$ Timeframe: Factor w/ 27 levels "1998-1999","1999-2000",..: 22 10 13 17 16 21 6 25 3 20 ...
 $ NULL: NULL
```

Comment: so how exactly are you trying to access the columns in the table? `data[[2]]$Fighter` is not ok?

Comment: Thanks alot, that worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is because there are multiple tables on that site. If you want a specific one, you need to specify it, e.g.:

```
library(magrittr)
xml2::read_html(url) %>% rvest::html_nodes(".tblRank") %>% rvest::html_table(header = TRUE)
```

Comment: thanks, but i still can't access the columns. If I for example use "colnames()" on the table the result is still NULL

Comment: Yes, either use `do.call(colnames, tableobject)` or just extract it first. `table <- table[[1]]`